# Changing Bootstrap's responsiveness

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, responsive-design

First of all, I am really new to Bootstrap so please excuse my newbiness.

The problem is that I am trying to create some sort of a thread list and when I shrink the width of the page all the contents keep moving down one another.

This is what I want:
http://img04.imgland.net/CmWzwDR.png
Things just becoming smaller and nothing going out of place

This is what happens:
http://img04.imgland.net/hNKc_Ok.png
Ya its pretty bad

Do you guys know of any way to fix this problem? I don't have to use bootstrap, but I thought it would be easiest.
Thanks

```
<div style={{marginTop: "80px", marginLeft: "20px", marginRight: "20px"}}>
  <div style = {{height: "80px", marginBottom: "10px", padding: "1px 1px 1px 1px", border: "2px solid #000000"}} class="row-fluid" >
     <div class = "col-xs-2" style= {{width: "20px", float: "left"}}>
       <div class = "row" > 
        <img src="img/upvote.png" />
        <img src="img/downvote.png" />
       </div>
     </div>

    <div class = "col-xs-2" style={{width: "100px", marginLeft: "0px", padding: "0px 0px 0px 0px", float: "left"}}> 
        <img src={thumbnail} style={{height: "80px", width: "100px"}}/>
    </div>

    <div class = "col-xs-8" style= {{marginLeft: "10px"}}>
        <div class = "row">
            <h3 style = {{height: "50px", textAlign: "left", marginTop: "0px", marginBottom: "0px", padding: "0px 0px 0px 0px"}}> {title} </h3>
            <p style = {{height: "30px", textAlign: "left", marginBottom: "0px", padding: "0px 0px 0px 0px", overflow: "hidden"}}> {desc} </p>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div> 
</div>
```

Currently this is my site on desktop screen:
img.imgland.net/5VBEme.png
And then this is what it would look like on mobile: img02.imgland.net/cr-MUQd.png

Comment: Could you add your code, way easier to help then :)

Comment: It might be really painful for you to look at but heres my code :p

Answer (score 2):

Without explicit samples of your code, I assume it has something to do with the grid prefix you are using. Take a look at http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options which shows the 4x different prefixes:

- .col-xs-*
- .col-sm-*
- .col-md-*
- .col-lg-*

To control the behaviour of your layout on mobile resolutions use the .col-xs-* class. Bootstrap documentation gives a great example: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed

The above exmaple shows how to mix classes to have different behaviour on different resolutions:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
</div>
```

Using this code will have your columns start at 50% wide on mobile and bump up to 33.3% wide on desktop. Using these combinations allows you to have quite a fine control over layout across all container resolutions.

**EDIT BASED ON CODE SUPPLIED:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <img src="img/upvote.png" />
            <img src="img/downvote.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2"> 
            <img src="#" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <h3>{title}</h3>
            <p>{desc}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Pay close attention to the Bootstrap docs which show how to use containers and the grid system. I would also take note of the Column nesting as this is a great way to show columns contained within columns: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting

**EDIT BASED ON SECONDARY QUESTION**

Use the element inspector function in your browser to have a detailed look at your CSS classes and what is creating the padding between columns. You can then call your own custom.css file ([or re-compile if you are competent with Less](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/)) which overrides the default Bootstrap styling. This will remove the left and right padding in the example code I have supplied:

```
.col-xs-2, .col-xs-8 {
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: I'll try it right now. Thanks for your help. I've also added my code but your eyes might hurt after looking at it

Comment: I would remove all inline styles and clean up the Bootstrap layout a bit. Should be:

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-*">
        <img src="img/upvote.png" />
        <img src="img/downvote.png" />
    </div>
<div>

float etc also not normally required, however Bootstrap also has helper classes called Quick Floats if needed: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It's exactly what I wanted. The only problem right now is all the white space between each column. Is it possible to resize the width of each column but still maintain the exact same responsiveness?

Comment: Updated to include custom css removing column left and right padding.